# Single-cell ATAC seq arrays

Tags: dna-sequencing, genomics, epigenetics

As part of a data analysis project, I encountered two kinds of single-cell assays
for transposase-accessible chromatin using sequencing ([single-cell ATAC seq](https://www.10xgenomics.com/solutions/single-cell-atac/)) methods. The first uses combinatorial indexing (also called *sci-ATAC seq*  [[link]](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature25981)), whereas the other counts the number of Tn5 cuts in peaks (called *sc-ATAC seq*  [[link]](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature14590)). I'm not a trained cell biologist or biotechnologist so I am possibly overlooking subtle similarities between the two methods here.

To my knowledge, sci-ATAC seq generates a binarised array, whereas sc-ATAC seq generates a counts matrix. (I'm also aware that there are post-processing tricks to convert binarised arrays to other array types, eg, normalised counts arrays.)

My question is, what about combinatorial indexing results in the array being binary rather than integer-valued? I'm looking for an explanation that relates the data collection method and combinatorial indexing with the resulting array type.

Thanks in advance!